# Can't run Flask app with gunicorn like service

Tags: python, linux, flask, service, gunicorn

I'm trying to make a service with run my Flask app with Gunicorn.
Service file look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=metrofind
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/geoMetroFinding/
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/geoMetroFinding/flaskenv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/geoMetroFinding/gunicorn.conf -b 0.0.0.0:5000 main_flask:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

in the log-error file it writes:

```
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

or

```
ImportError: No module named 'main_flask'
```

but in virtual env, all necessary packages were installed.

And when I run locally from directory "geoMetroFinding" in console this command:

```
  gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf -b 0.0.0.0:5000 main_flask:app
```

App is running

What is wrong?

Comment: Have the user (e.g. service user), which runs the program, all packages installed? You can login via 'su username' to install it by your own

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the environment in the service file.

An example of the [Service] section would be like this:

```
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/geoMetroFinding/
Environment="PATH=/home/ubuntu/geoMetroFinding/flaskenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/geoMetroFinding/flaskenv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/geoMetroFinding/gunicorn.conf -b 0.0.0.0:5000 main_flask:app
```

So you need to add the Environment to your PATH in order to make this work.

Take a look at [this great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I find, that I also don't correctly install packages on my virtual env